# Equality of string references in java

Tags: java, string, reference

Can you explain me why do I have "false" output? If I understand correctly, references point to the same object!

```
public class mainC {
    String str1,str2;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        mainC m=new mainC();
        m.str1="a";
        m.str2="b";
        System.out.print("m.str1 == m.str2: "+m.str1 == m.str2);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: @fge: They wouldn't even be `equals`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I should have read further...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m.str1` and `m.str2` point to *different* `String` objects, which is why you get `false`. The `==` compares `str1` and `str2`, **not** `m`.

---

Side note: Now, if you had:

```
m.str1="a";
m.str2="a"; // Same series of characters, e.g., "a"
```

...you'd be getting `true`, but it would be misleading. `==` compares *object references*. So you can have two different `String` objects that have the same characters in them, but they would not be `==` to each other (in fact, that's quite common). To compare strings, you use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). The reason my example above returns true is that both strings are initialized pointing to *literals*, and `String` literals in Java are [`intern`'d](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) by default, so that literals with the same characters are mapped to the same object.

Comment: So, they're both in String Literal Pool, but they have different objects because of different values? And if I create one new object of mainC class, then assign str2 as "a" and then try to compare them (==), I'll have true result. Correct?

Comment: @GeorgeRevkov: *"So, they're both in String Literal Pool, but they have different objects because of different values?"* Right. Literals with different sequences of characters will be different objects. *"And if I create one new object of mainC class, then assign str2 as "a" and then try to compare them (==), I'll have true result."* It doesn't matter how many objects you create. If you assign a **literal** `"a"` to them, you'll get the same `"a"` object each time (and similarly for the `"b"` object, which is different from the `"a"` object). Because literals are interned.

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between `"a"` and `new String("a")` - play around with equals to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

A string in Java is implemented as a [reference type and not a value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201329/does-java-make-distinction-between-value-type-and-reference-type). Since this is the case, their pointers in memory aren't equal. To get around this, [you can use their equals function to compare them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Downvoter, feel free to comment. :)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but `"a".equals("b")` will still return false!

Comment: It looks like his question itself is contradictory. :)