# What is real time use virtual and new,override methods in c#..?

Tags: c#, class

If I am having base class like below:

```
class A
{
  public virtual void print()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Base class method");   
      Console.Read();
    }

}
```

And derived class which inherited from base class like below:

```
class B : A
{
    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Class Method");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Main method to to create the objects is below:

```
class Method
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       A obj=new B();
       obj.Print();  
    }
 }
```

The above code will invoke the child class method. But even if I created object like `B obj=new B()` and did 'obj.Print()', the same output would be rendered.

So what is the use creating object like `A obj=new B()` and calling method like above?

On the other hand, if I change derived class method as below:

```
public new void print()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Child Class Method");
    Console.Read();
}
```

And if do `A obj=new B()`, then `obj.print()` will invoke the base class method. The same if I do `A obj=new A()` and `obj.print()`.

So what is the point of having a base class reference variable pointing to a derived reference class object and invoking the members like above? At which scenarios should this logic be used?

Comment: Is it intended that in your `B` class the method name is `PrintMaessage`? Obviously, it's not going to call that if you call `obj.Print()` as I think you're implying.

Comment: One word: polymorphism.

Comment: @IanMcLaird--Yes of course..I edited the post.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172380/creating-variable-of-type-base-class-to-store-derived-class-object-in-c-shar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method with this signature:

```
void Print(ICollection<A> objects)
{
    foreach(var obj in objects)
    {
        obj.print();
    }
}
```

the `print` will use either `B` implementation or `A` implementation (for `A` it could be another child `C` that does not `new` the `print` method)
reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162547/6460438

Comment: This example would be more obviously on point if you used `A` instead of `var`.

Comment: Not really since the type is expressed by the parameter's type.

Comment: @Greg,Thanks a lot..the link which is provided was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'd do this is for polymorphism. For example, you might have a method:

```
void Process(A item)
{
  item.print();
}
```

Now you can say:

```
B b = new b();
Process(b);
```

And although the method takes an `A` it will dispatch to the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The guiding principle here is that, when you're dealing with objects, you should use the *broadest* type that meets your needs (The *least*-derived type).  This is sometimes expressed as "Code to an interface, not an implementation."  Don't get confused by that terminology, though.  Coding against a base class is also just fine, if that's the type that meets your needs.

The reason is simple:  It simplifies later maintenance and refactoring, and makes the code easier to reuse elsewhere.  The type of a variable makes promises about how that variable will work.  It's easier to make your functions more widely applicable if you make those promises wider.  When you choose a base class for your variable type, you can be more confident about changing the underlying implementation later.

In your example, if I code against `A`, but create an instance of `B`, I can be pretty confident that later, when I add a `class C : A { ... }` that I could use it in this function if I wanted to.  If I code against `B` directly, that's harder to prove.

As for how those keywords relate to this:

`virtual` is used to mark a method as being one that a subclass can redefine (in fact, we probably *expect* subclasses to redefine it, at least occasionally).  You use this when there's a reasonable default implementation that will work most of the time, but still want to give a subclass a way to potentially optimize the function for its own use.

`abstract` is used to indicate that this class expects a subclass to "fill in" some missing details.  You use this when there's no way to know how to implement a method, but you know you'll need the method.  `abstract` methods are always `virtual`.  If a `class` defines any `abstract` methods, then the class itself must be `abstract` and you can't actually create an instance of it.  In my own experience, I use `abstract` more than `virtual`.

`override` is used to indicate that this class is *actually* (re-)defining the behavior of the parent class.

`new` in this context is slightly special.  Since a parent class must explicitly grant permission to its subclasses to redefine a method, we can't just `override` wherever we want.  That's usually a *good* thing, but sometimes, you need to step outside the rules.  (That jerk library author "forgot" to make a method `virtual` and we have a major optimization that we need to perform...)  That's what `new` is for.  It gives us a way around the normal inheritance rules should they get in the way.  You should use this *very* sparingly.