# strange behavior : How elements are inserted in vba arrays?

Tags: arrays, vba, reference

Can any one explain me the following code behavior ?? -->

```
Public Type User
    firstName          As String
    lastName           As String
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim userList(1) As User
    Dim user1       As User
    user1.firstName = "Tom"
    user1.lastName = "Hanks"
    
    userList(0) = user1
    Debug.Print "0 userList(0).firstName=" & userList(0).firstName & " userList(0).lastName=" & userList(0).lastName
    user1.lastName = "Cruise"
    Debug.Print "1 userList(0).firstName=" & userList(0).firstName & " userList(0).lastName=" & userList(0).lastName

End Sub
```

And the console displays :

```
0 userList(0).firstName=Tom userList(0).lastName=Hanks
```

```
1 userList(0).firstName=Tom userList(0).lastName=Hanks
```

So my question is : why the console does not display

```
1 userList(0).firstName=Tom userList(0).lastName=Cruise
```

?

It looks like if vba insert a copy of the object I want to insert but not the original object.

Thanks for your answers.

This problem just happend, I did not succeed to solve it, but if I can't probably I will change my code so that all the initialization of the object will be done before the insertion in the array, but it is not very clean IMHO.

Comment: Example: A=0, B=6 then A=B after it A=6. If you change B=100 then A will not be 100.

Comment: `userList(0).lastName = "Cruise"` will return your expected behaviour

Comment: You're right with integers but with user defined objects, vba should sotre the references of the object in an array, so since user1 and userList(0) refer to the same reference, modifying user1 should have effect on userList(0). That's what happens for example in java.

Comment: A user defined type is not an object! Otherwise you would have to use `Set userList(0) = user1`. If you want a user object you have to create a class.

Comment: Interesting, maybe it will work if I replace my initialization with yours, but what is a user defined object if this is not an object ?

Comment: Like I said it is not an object. If you want a "userdefined object" you have to create a class with properties firstName and lastName.

Comment: @LomicLegone If you're familiar with Java, then a `Type` in VBA is a [value type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201337/11683), as opposed to a `Class` which is a reference type.

Comment: @LomicLegone or if you are familiar with C#, then a `Type` is a `struct` and not `class` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Usage of a Class

[image]

- This is just a simple example of what, IMO, you wanted to do. It barely 'scratches the surface'.
- The objects (`cUser`) are most often held in a collection (`users`) but you might as well use an array (`rCount` is the number of (data) rows (objects, `cUser`s)).

**Class Module e.g. `Class1`: Rename to **`cUser`** in the Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>)!!!**

```
Option Explicit

Public ID As Long
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName As String
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    ' Create a new collection that will hold all 'cUser' objects.
    Dim users As Collection: Set users = New Collection
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the range...
    
    Dim user As cUser, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Create a new 'user' object.
        Set user = New cUser
        ' Populate the 'user'.
        user.ID = rg.Cells(r, 1).Value
        user.FirstName = rg.Cells(r, 2).Value
        user.LastName = rg.Cells(r, 3).Value
        ' Add to the 'users' collection.
        users.Add user
    Next r
    
    ' Loop through all the elements ('cUser') in the 'users' collection
    ' and return each user's properties in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    For Each user In users
        Debug.Print user.ID & ". " & user.FirstName & " " & user.LastName
    Next user

End Sub
```

**Result in the Immediate window**

```
1. Tom Hanks
2. Jack Nicholson
3. Michael J. Fox
4. Robert De Niro
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

- The same using an array instead of a collection.

```vb
Sub TestArray()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    ' Define an array that will hold all 'cUser' objects.
    Dim ArrUsers() As cUser: ReDim ArrUsers(1 To rCount)
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the range...
    
    Dim user As cUser, r  As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        ' Create a new 'user' object.
        Set user = New cUser
        ' Populate the 'user'.
        user.ID = rg.Cells(r, 1).Value
        user.FirstName = rg.Cells(r, 2).Value
        user.LastName = rg.Cells(r, 3).Value
        ' Add to the 'ArrUsers' array.
        Set ArrUsers(r) = user
    Next r
    
    ' Loop through all the elements ('cUsers') in the 'ArrUsers' array
    ' and return each user's properties in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Debug.Print ArrUsers(r).ID & ". " & ArrUsers(r).FirstName _
            & " " & ArrUsers(r).LastName
    Next r

End Sub
```